# ( React.js ) Can I use a function thats placed in a different component?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, flow-router

I've got the mainComponent. Now Im rendering two different components based on 1>2, for example. Now How would can I use the data and function from a different component on another component

```
ComponentOne = React.createClass({
    render() {
        /* use theFunctionImTryingToRun  -output "a" */
    }
})



mainComponent = React.createClass({
      var x = ["a","b","c"];
   theFunctionImTryingToRun: function(){
        console.log(x[0]);

},
 mainRender: function(){
  if (1<2) {
    return (<ComponentOne /> );  
} else {
  return (<ComponentTwo />);
}

}

render() {
        return  <div> {this.mainRender()} </div>
    }
})
```

Comment: you can pass functions along with props between components `<ComponentOne callback={this.function}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*MainComponent*

```
var MainComponent = React.createClass({    
  theFunctionImTryingToRun: function() {
    var x = ["a","b","c"];
    console.log(x[0]);
  },

  render: function() {
    return 1 < 2 ?
      <ComponentOne myFunction={this.theFunctionImTryingToRun} /> :
      <ComponentTwo />;
  }  
});
```

*ComponentOne*

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({   
    render: function() {
        this.props.myFunction();
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
    }
});
```